# How can I use biblatex to respect Physical Review A - style pagination (pagination by article, plus a prefix)?

Tags: biblatex

In a work I am typesetting, the author cites a Physical Review A paper.  [Specifically, this one: http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.86.013612 .]

Not only does this journal renew pagination with each article, it prefixes the article number with each page: e.g., the above article goes from page 013612-1 to page 013612-5.

I have attempted to use `biblatex`'s `pagination` field with a custom entry to prefix the article number, but this method only works for inline citations, and doesn't repeat the prefix for a multi-page citation; moreover, in this work, I really only need page numbers for the reference list.

> How can I prefix the article number to the page number in the reference list (for this reference only)?

MWE -- .bib file

```
@article{cart1,
   title = {Model of a $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Bose-Einstein condensate in a $\delta${}-function double-well potential},
  author = {Cartarius, Holger and Wunner, G\"unter},
journaltitle = {Physical Review A},
    date = {2012-07-09},
  volume = {86},
  number = {1},
   pages = {1-5},
pagination = {jnum1},
    misc = {013612},
publisher = {American Physical Society},
     doi = {10.1103/PhysRevA.86.013612},
     url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.86.013612},
}
```

MWE -- .tex file

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\NewBibliographyString{jnum1,jnum1s}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
jnum1 = {013612--},
jnum1s = {013612--},
}
\addbibresource{biblatest.refs.bib}

\begin{document}
Something else. See \cite[1--3]{cart1}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Note:** The obvious question is, "Do you really need to do this?" This will eventually depend on the publisher, but for the `arXiv` version I would prefer to match the original text [unless I am violating some cardinal rule].

---

**Edit:** The above code produces the following output:

[image: original output]

As you see, the default is to include the pages field in the end-of-paper reference list.

Comment: IMHO, you do not need to cite the particular page of an article. They're usually short enough that people can find what you're talking about in the article without a specific page number. Therefore, for articles, the citation is all about helping other people find the work that you cite, for which, the most important thing is the paper number in this case, and I don't think you should worry about the internal pages. A book is obviously completely different, but they also have different reference styles that make sense for a book.

Comment: @darthbith That would certainly be unacceptable in my field. A direct quotation would need a specific page. But, also, the entry in the list of references would have to include the page range. However, there are some cases where this doesn't make sense. For example, advance access but there it is really because the final pagination is not yet known. @user527733 Could you not just include the prefix in the `pages` field?

Comment: @cfr Interesting, I've never seen an specific pages from an article referenced, always just the whole work. Guess every field is different :-) In this case though, the page range for the list of references would just indicate the length of the paper, which doesn't seem to aid in finding the paper in the journal... For instance, for the article cited above, the search feature on the AIP website just needs the article number (i.e. the prefix), not the prefix + the page range.

Comment: @darthbith I tend to agree. I think this is close to the advance access case i.e. the page numbers have no real meaning except for citations within the paper. But since the OP said that didn't apply, that's not a problem. But I can't see why the prefix can't be included in the `pages` field if for some reason the OP does want to include this information.

Comment: I think it would certainly be acceptable to just cite page 1 or 4, instead of 013612-1 or 013612-4 - especially since the "mapping" between the two is clear. For your solution to work you need `bookpagination = {jnum1},` as well as `pagination = {jnum1},` in the `bib` file. But of course that becomes unpracticable if you have more of these articles flying around, you would have to create a new bibstring for each, that should be done automatically.

Comment: Looking at the website though, I come to think that `013612` is the "pages" number within the journal and that 1 to 5 are the physical pages therein. So probably `pages = {013612}` and just using the optional prenote argument with bare page numbers is closest to the intended meaning, it is easiest to implement and less intrusive than the very long page numbers that no-one can parse properly. (If you [try to export the citation](https://journals.aps.org/pra/export/10.1103/PhysRevA.86.013612) from the website above, this is exactly what happens, the `pages` field is `013612` there).

Comment: I'd put the number `013612` into biblatex' `eid` field, and `1--5` into `pages`. `013612` is the article ID, not a page.

Comment: @darthbith , the page numbering probably will not be referred to in the text, but does appear in the reference list, [as my edit shows], so I'm stuck thinking about it.  

I could just follow @cfr 's and @moewe 's idea and just put the article ID by itself in the `pages` field, or follow @Alex 's suggestion and put it in the `note` or `eid` fields.  What I cannot do is write something akin to `pages = {013612-1--013612-5}`, as this violates `biblatex` 's expectation of a number range and the output reads "pages." -- i.e., it can't read it in that form.

Comment: @user52733 I agree with @cfr and @moewe in general - just put the article number in the `pages` field, as @tohecz has suggested in their answer, and omit the `1-5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see *any* reason why not to use the BibTeX citation generated by the journal:

```
@article{PhysRevA.86.013612,
  title = {Model of a PT-symmetric Bose-Einstein condensate in a $\delta${}-function double-well potential},
  author = {Cartarius, Holger and Wunner, G\"unter},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. A},
  volume = {86},
  issue = {1},
  pages = {013612},
  numpages = {5},
  year = {2012},
  month = {Jul},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevA.86.013612},
  url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.86.013612}
}
```

The fact that the page number is prefixed by the article number doesn't change the fact that the article's page numbers are `1--5`. Therefore `\cite[pp.~1--3]{PhysRevA.86.013612}` is entirely correct.

**Erratum.** There is a reason why not to use the given format directly -- the title is improprely capitalized:

```
  title = {Model of a {PT}-symmetric {Bose-Einstein} condensate in a $\delta${}-function double-well potential},
```

Comment: I absolutely agree, I would suggest `\cite[1--3]{PhysRevA.86.013612}` though, as `biblatex` is perfectly able to add the page prefix itself.

Comment: @moewe OTOH, usage of pagination prefix can become a burden if you use `\cite[Theorem~3.5]{A}` at one place, `\cite[§~5]{B}` at another place and `\cite[pp.~1--3]{C}` at yet another place.

Comment: You are certainly right, though I feel that this is one of the strong points of this system: One can just specify the pagination "style" (on an entry-type basis) and does not need to bother with these types any more.

Comment: @moewe Not all automation is good. I can't imagine I set up a style seperately for each entry just because I happen to have 10 different things I cite from different sources.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. If you use the prefix for pagination as default `\cite[1--3]{...}` will add the prefix but `\cite[Theorem~3.5]{...}` will not. It'll only add the prefix if the content of the argument meets certain criteria.

Comment: @cfr Yeah, and I have to remember this inconsistency. No, thanks.

Comment: I think of it as overriding a default rather than an inconsistency. A bit like specifying an optional alternative title for use in headings or the ToC. But each to their own... ;).